# Weird HTTP data accumulation on App Engine with Python and CouchDB

Tags: python, json, http, google-app-engine, couchdb

I'm trying to make a relatively simple App Engine app to fetch some pages on a daily basis and post the data to a CouchDB server. I've got the following code in my App Engine app (with the couchdb-python library):

```
    # post the result to CouchDB
    price_data = {
      'source': 'blah',
      'date': str(result.headers['date'])
    }
    db.save(price_data)
    db.put_attachment(price_data, file_one, 'prices_one.txt')
    db.put_attachment(price_data, file_two, 'prices_two.txt')
```

`file_one` and `file_two` are the results from earlier urlfetch requests.

Now this all works fine except that the first attachment gets posted with the `price_data JSON ({ 'source': 'blah', 'date': 'date here'})` at the beginning of the `prices_one` text file, and the second attachment gets prefixed with both the `price_data` JSON as well as the whole `prices_one` text file, followed by the actual `prices_two.txt` file.
I'm sure if I tried to add a third attachment, it would post all the accumulated data to that one.
If I go on CouchDB to look at the file in the DB, it's the full file, just with `{ 'source': 'blah', 'date': 'date here'}` at the very beginning.

Any ideas what could be causing App Engine to keep resending the previous data with each new HTTP POST? Also, I should note that it was doing the same thing before I started using the couchdb-python library, so it seems to be something App Engine related that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

During your investigation, try to use a raw HTTP library instead of a CouchDB library. I suggest the native App Engine library (`urlfetch` or perhaps `urllib2`). The CouchDB API is very simple, you will not have difficulty.

Is there a difference in the result?

Comment: I tried again with urlfetch and it seems to be working, so apparently I was mistaken about having the problem before using the couchdb library. Thanks!